# Automate locale changes on Linux

Tags: linux, locale

I'm finding it quite tricky to programmatically change `locales` on Ubuntu and CentOS. I find many guides on using the console interface like [here](https://linuxconfig.org/change-system-language-on-ubuntu-20-04-from-command-line), manually stepping through things, but I want to automate my configuration on a new system. What command do I run so that all output from `locale` will show `en_GB.UTF-8` on all of the following so that I can automate this on any new install?

```
$ locale
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: One could achieve this by writing a shell script (e.g. for the initialisation of a new system) for each of the distros. I think this is distribution dependent, Ubuntu perhaps using something with `dpkg-reconfigure`.

Comment: I've kind of been trying that, or at least, googling on how to do that, I just come up with guides on how to go through the dpkg-reconfigure `curses` interface as a manual install. I've just found this page, I'll report back if this one works (but 6 years old means it might not, Linux changes a lot between distros). https://askubuntu.com/questions/683406/how-to-automate-dpkg-reconfigure-locales-with-one-command

Comment: OK, do let us know, I could not say how. Perhaps someone will know.

Answer (score 0):

The following 3 methods all seem to work in Ubuntu:

```
sudo update-locale "LANG=en_GB.UTF-8"; sudo locale-gen --purge "en_GB.UTF-8"; sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive locales

echo "en_GB.UTF-8" | sudo tee -a /etc/locale.gen; sudo locale-gen

sudo update-locale LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

However, after doing this, when I type `locale`, it still shows as unconfigured. I have to reboot or open a new bash shell for the configuration to be applied, I don't know a workaround for that.